# Create Azure DevOps release without artifacts via Rest API

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api

I am building a JSON body based on the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#examples). It looks like this (copied from the documentation):

```
{
  "definitionId": 1,
  "description": "Creating Sample release",
  "artifacts": [
    {
      "alias": "Fabrikam.CI",
      "instanceReference": {
        "id": "2",
        "name": null
      }
    }
  ],
  "isDraft": false,
  "reason": "none",
  "manualEnvironments": null
}
```

However, there aren't any artifacts for this release. It's just stages that need to run. I have tried setting the "artifacts" value to null and false. I also tried removing the "artifacts" key altogether, like this:

```
{
  "definitionId": 1,
  "description": "Creating Sample release",
  "isDraft": false,
  "reason": "none",
  "manualEnvironments": null
}
```

Unfortunately, all of these guesses just throw one of these errors:

```
The artifact alias cannot be empty. Specify a valid artifact alias and try again.
```

or

```
Release pipeline name cannot be empty. Specify a name and try again.
```

**How do I create a release that doesn't include artifacts using the REST API?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I create a release that doesn't include artifacts using the
>   REST API?

Just leave it blank and it will work. Use format like this:

```
{
  "definitionId": 1,
  "description": "Creating Sample release",
  "artifacts": [],
  "isDraft": false,
  "reason": "none",
  "manualEnvironments": null
}
```

If the response is 200 OK, it means you run the rest api successfully. (This api is used to create release instead of creating release pipeline, you should know that! )